# Display error message to users

Tags: error-handling

I have an event receiver that copies items to another list. I however need to show errors to the user that the item did not copy.

```
try
                    {
                       //copy code works here
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ILogger logger = new ULSLogger();
                        logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                    }
```

Would it be good coding practice to change the catch block to the below:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ILogger logger = new ULSLogger();
                            logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);

                            properties.Cancel = true;
                            properties.ErrorMessage = "Items not copied";
                        }
```

Comment: What event is your event receiver attached to? (ItemAdded, ItemUpdated, etc.)

Comment: It's attached to the ItemUpdated

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `SPException` so that the masterpage is wrapped in the error.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
 throw new SPException("Items not copied + "\n" + ex.Message");
}
```

If you use `SPException`, the error will also be logged to the ULS which is very useful and good practice.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/01/21/dev-tip-throwing-spexceptions.aspx